# Find out app identifier (usually a reverse DNS string) for "defaults" command

Tags: macos, command-line, settings, customization

I would like to disable hold and press for Hyper Terminal. I have already successfully done so for VS Code using the following recipe:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44010683/7483211

My problem is that I don't know the app identifier I need to put in instead of `com.microsoft.VSCode`.

How do I find this out for an app?

Comment: Thanks @jaume for making the title more precise, had I known that this is called the app identifier I may have not need to task the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually not called an "app identifier" (that's something slightly different) - the correct name is "bundle identifier".

You can find it by looking in the `Info.plist` file in the `Contents` folder of any macOS application. For example for Visual Studio Code, it would typically be located in:

```
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

You need to look for the key named `CFBundleIdentifier` - it will look something like this:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.microsoft.VSCode</string>
```

Comment: Note that the contents of applications are normally hidden in the Finder. To drill into them, right-click (/control-click/whatever-secondary-click-is-configured-as-on-your-Mac) on the application, and choose Show Package Contents from the contextual menu. Also, the easiest way to view .plist files in the Finder is with Quick Look -- select the .plist file, and press Command-Y or choose File menu > Quick Look [appname] (or just press spacebar, but if you have the filename selected that'll try to rename it instead).

Answer (score 2):

I figured out one way by going through `defaults` help:

```
defaults read | grep hyper
```

This outputs:

```
   "co.zeit.hyper" =     {
                "bundle-id" = "co.zeit.hyper";
```

So in my case the answer is `co.zeit.hyper`.

There may be a better way, but this works if you can guess part of the app name correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the bundle identifier. You can use:

`defaults write -app VSCode ...`

or whatever the name of the app is.