# Individual accent colors for Mac OS Apps?

Tags: macos, applications, mail.app, system-settings, preferences

I'd like to change the individual accent colors of my apps in Mac OS (so that they arent all the same). I'd like to change my Mail app accent colors to blue specifically. Is there a way to do this without changing the accent colors of every app to blue?

Comment: Let me look up mail’s reverse domain name for the preference to try something like this… https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/466986/5472

Comment: This is really an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) You'd already found *how* to do it as you'd posted this on bmike's linked question - all you need now is the domain name/Bundle ID.

Comment: @bmike thank you. is there a good directory available with all reverse domain names?

Comment: No, you will have to find it from the app you are interested in (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/425089/37797), Mail.app is `com.apple.mail`

Comment: So the terminal command 

`defaults write com.apple.mail AppleAccentColor -integer 4`

should work, but doesn't?

Comment: It works for me with other colours than 4 (as 4 is my system-wide setting). Is it just 4 that it doesn't work for you with? If you're having trouble with Mail specifically and/or certain colours, [edit] your question with details to reopen it as it would be different from existing questions then.

Comment: You don't need the domain name. You can use `defaults write -app Mail` instead.

Comment: @grg I get the following `Could not write domain; exiting` which i guess means terminal doesn't have the appropriate permissions?

Comment: @grg - Is the issue the permissions settings since Catalina?

Comment: @benwiggy I didn't realise that worked properly with sandboxed apps nowadays! That's a nice answer to the linked question https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/425089/37797 if you fancy posting that

Comment: @Charles You need to give Terminal Full Disk Access in System Settings → Privacy to be able to access other app containers.